# Python SDK Wit.ai "unable to retrieve libwit"

Tags: python, pip, wit.ai

I am following the quickstart for wit.ai: [here](https://wit.ai/docs/python/1.0.0/quickstart)

But when I write

```
pip install wit
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception: unable to retrieve libwit
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: It seems like libwit doesn't exist in pip collection..use "pip search libwit"  to verify

Comment: What operating system you are working on WIndows or Linux?..follow the instruction on the site to manually install wit...specifically if you are working on debian linux...just use "apt-get install python-wit" (assumming the package is in your OS repository)

Comment: I am on Windows. It gives the same error as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just try:

```
git clone https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit
python setup.py install
```

See more information from https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit.